# n-tuples notation confusion

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I am slightly confused with Cox, Little, O'Shea's *Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms*.

So, it talks about $n$-tuples $\alpha = (a_1,a_2,...,a_n) \in k^n$ where $k$ denotes a field. So, when I wish to point out the $i$th element of this $\alpha$, I'd say $a_i$. And so does the book through the first chapter and up to this point where it mentions a lemma about well-ordering, in the topic of monomial ordering.

Here it is,

> An order relation $>$ on $\mathbb{Z}^n_{\geq0}$ is a well-ordering if and only if every strictly decreasing sequence in $\mathbb{Z}^n_{\geq0}$
>
> $$\alpha(1)>\alpha(2)>\alpha(3)>...$$
>
> eventually terminates.

So, what are $\alpha(1)$ etc? It's as if $\alpha$ is a function, is $\alpha(i)=\alpha_i$? the $i$th element? If so, why did he have to use this notation which he's never used before in the book or explained what it was?

Anyway, if someone knows what it means, please kindly tell me... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\alpha (k)$ are each individual different n-tuples and the ordering is an attempt to order the n-tuples, not the terms of the n tuples.  $\alpha (1)$ = ($a_1, a_2... $) and $\alpha (2) = (b_1, b_2...) $ and so on.

Comment: Cheers, that should be it :)